# Mean AUC vs Mean Average Precision?

Tags: ranking, auc, average-precision

Both AUC and Average Precision (AP) are commonly used to evaluate the quality of a ranked list of relevant / irrelevant documents. When evaluating a search engine, we want to evaluate the quality over multiple queries, therefore we naturally define [MAP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_measures_(information_retrieval)#Mean_average_precision), the mean AP over multiple queries. Similarly, why don't we define MAUC, the mean AUC over multiple queries?